# jQuery variable scope - variable does not change its value

Tags: jquery, variables

I have some code where I define a variable to be a certain value, but then, during an ajax request, that value has to be changed. When I alert to check that the value has changed, the variable still has the old value. The variable in question is 'action'. Please take a look:

```
$(function(){
    var $action; //this one is the problem
    var $mod;

    $(".main-nav li > a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(".inner-nav").hide();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children("a").attr("id","");

        if ($(this).attr('id')=='nav-active')
        {
            $(this).attr('id','');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr('id','nav-active');
        }

        $(this).parent().find(".inner-nav").toggle();
    });

    $(".main-nav li .inner-nav li a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find("a").attr("id","");
        $(".main-nav .inner-nav li a").attr("id","");

        $(this).attr('id','nav-active');

        // ajax

        var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
        var rel_arr = rel.split(',');

        $action = rel_arr[0]; //first change of value
        $mod = rel_arr[1];

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxLoad.php?action='+$action+'&mod='+$mod,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                $(".content div").html("");

                $action = response.ajax.action; //second change of value
                $mod = response.ajax.mod;

                $.each(response.data, function(id, product){
                    $(".content > div").append("<div>"+product.name+"</div>");
                });
            }
        });

        alert ($action); //prints out the first value

        // Set document title
        var parentClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a").html();
        document.title = parentClass + " :: " + $(this).html();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are done asynchronously, so control returns to your script immediately.  Code you place after the `$.ajax` call runs after the ajax request has been *initiated* but before the ajax has completed.  If you want something to run after the ajax has completed, you have to put it in your success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It has to do with Chad's contribution saying that the problem lies within the request being done asynchronously. To fix this, I had to do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false, //add this
    cache: false, //and this
    url: 'ajaxLoad.php?action='+$action+'&mod='+$mod,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        $(".content div").html("");

        $action = response.ajax.action;
        $mod = response.ajax.mod;

        $.each(response.data, function(id, product){
            $(".content > div").append("<div>"+product.name+"</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If you do that, Chrome will tell you, "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."  It may work, but it's a Bad Idea.  You should find a way to get the job done with `async: true`, where you do what you need to within the success callback.